# .Closest() with Classes seems not to pick correct element

Tags: jquery, html

Trying to select the closest of a specific class to the selected element (in this case a button within the last td) however once i put a class onto the specific element .closest() , .siblings() ,  and .parents() dont seem to work.

```
<head>
  <style>
  .ancestors * { 
    display: block;
    border: 2px solid lightgrey;
    color: lightgrey;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 15px;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("span").closest("ul td .here").css({"color": "red", "border": "2px solid red"});
  });
  </script>
</head>

<body class="ancestors">body (great-great-grandparent)
  <div style="width:500px;">div (great-grandparent)
    <ul>ul (second ancestor - second grandparent) 
      <ul><td class='here'>ul (first ancestor - first grandparent) in a td</td>
        <li>li (direct parent)
          <span>span</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </ul>   
  </div>
</body>
```

im expecting for the ul with the td with the class of "here" to add css and display in red the code above is an adaptation of a w3 schools try it editor 
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_closest.asp

after adding the clas it no longer works but works wth the td added (.closest("ul td .here")) have tried just .here as a selector too

Comment: A `<td>` should not be the child of a `<ul>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("ul.here").css({"color": "red", "border": "2px solid red"});
});
```

```css
.ancestors * { 
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid lightgrey;
  color: lightgrey;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body class="ancestors">body (great-great-grandparent)
  <div style="width:500px;">div (great-grandparent)
    <ul>ul (second ancestor - second grandparent) 
      <ul class='here'>
        ul (first ancestor - first grandparent) in a td
           <li>li (direct parent)
              <span>span</span>
            </li>
      </ul>
    </ul>   
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML is invalid. You should use [a validation service](https://validator.nu/).

Only `<li>` elements can be children of `<ul>` elements. `<td>` elements can only be children of `<tr>` elements.

The HTML parser in Chrome (other browsers will behave in a similar way) discards the invalid `<td>` element entirely.

Consequently, `ul td .here` doesn't match any element.

**Write valid HTML**.

In addition, you have a descendant combinator between `td` and `.here` so you would match a **descendant** of a `<td>` element that is a member of the `here` class, not a `<td>` element that is, itself, a member of that class.

Comment: Apologies on the incorrect html, Something like <tr><td><div class='here'></div></td></tr> is closer to the code im actually using where im using .closest() in a <tr><td onclick==selectClosest(this)'></td></tr>